# PhpUnit giving errror at second test function

Tags: testing, phpunit, laravel-5, sql-insert

I am trying to make test to my Database with phpunit and I migrate the database to memory.

the first test run just fine:

```
  /** @test */
     public function it_fetches_a_single_ano_letivo()
     {
         $this->makeAnoLetivo();

         $this->getJson('/v1/anos-letivos');

         $this->assertResponseOk();
     }
```

but the second test fails and its exactly the same as the first one:

```
     /** @test */
         public function it_fetches_anos_letivos()
         {
             $this->makeAnoLetivo();

             $this->getJson('/v1/anos-letivos');

             $this->assertResponseOk();
         }
```

Here is the makeAnoLetivo function:

```
 private function makeAnoLetivo($anoLetivoFields = [])
     {
         while($this->times--)
         {
             $ano1=$this->fake->year;

             $anoLetivo = array_merge([
                 'ano1' => $ano1+0,
                 'ano2' => $ano1+1
             ], $anoLetivoFields);

             AnoLetivo::create($anoLetivo);

         }
      }
```

and here is the phpUnit output:

```
Configuration read from {{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/phpunit.xml

..E

Time: 2.62 seconds, Memory: 23.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) AnosLetivosTest::it_fetches_anos_letivos
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 anos_letivos.id may not be NULL (SQL: insert into "anos_letivos" ("ano1", "ano2", "updated_at", "created_at") values (2009, 2010, 2015-03-27 18:41:59, 2015-03-27 18:41:59))

{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:620
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:576
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:359
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:316
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1702
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:933
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1603
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1603
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1501
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:544
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/tests/AnosLetivosTest.php:50
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/tests/AnosLetivosTest.php:32
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:152
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:104

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 anos_letivos.id may not be NULL

{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:358
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:612
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:576
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:359
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:316
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1702
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:933
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1603
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1603
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1501
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:544
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/tests/AnosLetivosTest.php:50
{{PATH_TO_PROJECT}}/tests/AnosLetivosTest.php:32
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:152
phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:104

FAILURES!                          
Tests: 3, Assertions: 5, Errors: 1.
```

So the first function run just fine but the second one is the same and fails...
Also if i create a third one (equal) only the first one will pass.

**EDIT 1:**
So it inserts well in the first test, it rollbacks the DB and Migrates it again for the next test and the insert in the database says the ID may not be NULL, so it seems the create method no longer knows how to insert in the database after the first test... still dont know what causes this, the migrate is correct and it is rollback"ing" well too...

**Edit 2:**
I tried to run the tests against the production database and it works just fine. So the problem must be on the memory database or on any configuration on this memory database. But I dont know what problem because the first test I get green and it inserts the data without problems, i can even insert 10 items in the first test and it does what it should. But the second test shows the error above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the solution was to write this lines on the setUp() method:

```
AnoLetivo::flushEventListeners();
AnoLetivo::boot();
```

the problem may be in the laravel framework.

Comment: Why don't you `use DatabaseMigrations;`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the database insert command is failing after the first test. Could be for a number of reasons.

I think you should consider using https://github.com/laracasts/TestDummy - it is designed to allow you to have fake data for all your tests. It will also automatically reset your database between each test (using transactions).

Its a wonderful tool - give it a go

Comment: @Pedro Silva - did that help with your question? Do you need more info?

Comment: I will give it a try, but i dont get why it is failing, if in the first test i insert 100 times it doesnt fail...

Comment: Well testDummy did not solve the problem, I still get the insert error in the DB... :S

Comment: i think its something to do with this github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181 and you have commented there, do you know anything about this in laravel 5?